# Template change according to condition in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have template for dashobaord with header,fooyter and content.i need another template should load for some condtion in angular 6.this is my current template for dashboard

```
<app-header></app-header>
    <div class="wrapper">
     -------
    </div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and i need to load another component `<app-no-permission ></app-no-permission>` for some condition.

this is my dashboard.component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.menuAccessCheck(this.router.url).subscribe(datas => {
      this.menuAccess = datas;
      if(this.menuAccess.data.can_view==1){
        //load normal template
      }else{
        //load app-no-permission template
      }
    });
```

Comment: This is Angular basics. I urge you to read [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#conditional-display-with-ngif) before posting a question, and when you do, please follow [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NgIf` to do that. Let's assume that `this.menuAccess.data.can_view` can be 1 or 2. This is what the `.html` should looks like:

```
<app-header></app-header>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <span *ngIf="menuAccess.data.can_view == 1"> Showwing ONE</span>
       <span *ngIf="menuAccess.data.can_view == 2"> Showwing TWO</span>
    </div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Just change the `span` with whatever you want and you have your logic working.

Comment: i dont want heade and footer for second condition..only <app-no-permission ></app-no-permission> component

Comment: Then just apply the `ngIf` to `app-no-permission` if `menuAccess.data.can_view == something`